# Is resolution complete or only refutation-complete?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Going through [some knowledge representation tutorials](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~sheila/384/w11/) on resolution at the moment, and I came across [slide 05.KR, no77](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~sheila/384/w11/Lectures/csc384w11-Lecture-05-KR.pdf).

There it is mentioned that "the procedure is also complete".

I think this completeness can not mean that if a sentence is entailed by KB, then it will be derived by resolution. For example, resolution can not derive $(q \lor \neg q)$ from a KB with single clause $\neg p$. (Example from KRR, Brachman and Levesque, page 53).

Could anyone help me figure out what is meant in this slide? Is the completeness of slide refer to being refutaton-complete and not a complete proof procedure?

Comment: Have you read the fine print on the slide? If KB entails $f$, then you can refute KB$\land\lnot f$ using resolution.

Comment: I was able to remove some jargon, but was are "KB" and "KRR"?

Comment: @Raphael probably Knowledge Base (set of true sentences) and Knowledge Representation and Reasoning.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Resolution is complete as a refutation system. That is, if $S$ is a contradictory set of clauses, then resolution can refute $S$, i.e. $S \vdash \bot$.

This is sufficient since $T \vdash A$ is equivalent to $T \cup \{\lnot A\} \vdash \bot$. So if we want to see a formula $A$ is derivable from $T$, we only need to check if there is a refutation proof for $T \cup \{\lnot A\}$ which can be checked using resolution.

Answer (score 8):

Resolution is only refutationally complete, as you mentioned. This is *intended* and very useful, because it drastically reduces the search space. Instead of having to eventually derive every possible consequence (to find a proof of some conjecture), resolution is only trying to derive the empty clause.

Answer (score 2):

It is also implicationally complete in the following sense:

If a set of clauses $F$ implies a non tautological clause $C$, then it is always possible to derive a single clause $C'$ that subsumes $C$
(i.e. $C' \subseteq C$).

Source:
[Christian G. Fermüller, Implicational Completeness of Signed Resolution, 2002](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-46508-1_11)

Note that the original result is refered to:
R.C.T. Lee.
A completeness theorem and a computer program for  nding theorems
derivable from given axioms
. Ph.D. Thesis, University of California, Berkely, 1967.